# How to remove scientific notation?

Tags: r

When I try removing scientific notation, the number gets converted to character. Can we not remove scientific notation and still keep the output as numeric?

```
numb <- 20172334534654e-08
class(format(numb, scientific = F))
```

Comment: You can at any rate convert back: `numb <- as.numeric(format(numb, scientific = F))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `options`

```
 options(scipen = 999)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this CODE as akrun suggests:

```
options(scipen=999)
```

or

```
format(99999999,scientific = FALSE)
```

Comment: @akrun which OS has trouble with F/T?  I mean I agree it's better to specify but I haven't seen any OS specific issues regarding it.

Comment: Same to me. I don't know why?

Comment: @TarJae Some people will downvote answers if they think the question is a duplicate.  I don't agree with the practice but I've heard of it occurring.